# Gradle - private tasks and task types

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to use Gradle's very handy Task Types to handle parts of my build, but not expose those parts to the build caller?

My goal is this: have a gradle build that does a single thing, `dist`.

`dist` is really comprised of a view different pieces, say:

- create some directories
- copy some files there
- zip them up

I have a few ways of doing this:

#### 1) Create 3 Tasks of types 'Directory', 'Copy', and 'Zip'

Great, but if I do this I'm exposing internal tasks.  I only want my build to expose one task, `dist`, I never want a user to run any other task.  This isn't possible AFAIK because Gradle doesn't support private / hidden tasks.

#### 2) Build private functions that do those pieces manually.

I can do this with AntTasks.  But Gradle already has these very useful Task Types that I feel like I should be able to leverage, no?  Otherwise I'm recreating the wheel.

I feel like there's got to be a clear way to achieve this.  If not then the use cases of Task Types are really restricted.

Comment: Sorry if I closed this prematurely. The answer to 2. is no, tasks can't be used as functions. There are some task-like functions on `Project` (e.g. `project.copy`), but this isn't a generic mechanism.

Comment: np, thanks Peter, your linked duped question was essentially what I needed

Comment: This answer was also very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18204587/295797