# What's the best choice between tasks or methods to organize your Gradle build logic?

Tags: methods, gradle, build, logic, task

I'm currently **migrating some old huge Maven 1 script to Gradle**.
As a consequence, I need to adapt the old Maven 1 / Ant & its goals logic to Gradle.

After having read the Gradle User Guide, and some articles on Gradle tasks and methods, **I am quite confused about the way to write my script**.

In the official [Gradle User Guide, §6.1](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#N101A9), it is explained that a **Gradle task**:

> represents some **atomic piece of work** which a build performs

In [§6.11](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#N1034A), it is also explained that we can use **methods to organize our build logic**.

So, my question is: **what's the correct way to use each of them?**

I am creating a build script so, **in my opinion**:

- **tasks should only be what the user is allowed to see**, and so, to call through the command line.
  By example `gradle doSomeInternalTechnicalWork` is not correct for me, as the user should even not know that `doSomeInternalTechnicalWork` exists.
  Always in my opinion, it should **NOT** be a task.
- **method should be used to organize the build logic, and should NOT be visible by the user**

With the former logic, **I encounter problems when my methods need to call Gradle tasks** (like the JAR creation of the Java plugin).

I know that [I should not call task from task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204077/can-i-call-a-gradle-task-from-a-groovy-method-in-a-gradle-file) (and so the same for task from method), but, have a look to this example:

```
task independentTask << {

   // initialization stuff 
   println "doing a lot of initialization" 

   // using methods to organize build logic, good or not?
   doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimself()
   }

task dependentTask(dependsOn: 'independentTask') << { 
   println "now that 'independentTask' is done, I can continue to do complex things..." 
   }

void doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimself() {
   println "doing really complex things"

   // I really need to create my JAR here and not somewhere else
   // And I know it's not a good thing to directly call the Action.execute
   jar.execute()

   println "doing other really complex things"
}
```

In this case, **what would be a correct build logic?**

Should `doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimself` be converted in 1 or more tasks, so as to be able to `dependsOn` the JAR task?
But that would mean to have really a lot of tasks, callable by the user, when, indeed, that should not be the case.

Comment: You'd better go with tasks, as they scale better and easier to manage. If you have a lot of code, try putting it in [`buildSrc` directory](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources) or even make a plugin. Also, the question looks to be opinion-based...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having search quite a lot, I concluded that, when you need to **call a task from another task**, you have little choice but to **rely on tasks relationships** (`dependsOn`, `mustRunAfter`, `finalizedBy`).

Which means that methods can't be used to organize the build logic in the same way that they are used to structure a program in Java, Groovy & Co.

As a consequence, you can't prevent the user from seeing (and using) some internal tasks, that should normally only be used as dependency by some other ones.

A "Gradle correct" version of the former build script would hence be:

```
task dependentTask(dependsOn: 'doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimselfPart2') << { 
   println "now that 'independentTask' is done, I can continue to do complex things..." 
}

task doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimselfPart2(dependsOn: ['doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimselfPart1', 'jar']) << {
   println "doing other really complex things"
}

task doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimselfPart1(dependsOn: 'independentTask') << {
   println "doing really complex things"
}

task independentTask << {
   // initialization stuff 
   println "doing a lot of initialization" 
}
```

Or, with **tasks relationships declared separately**:

```
task dependentTask << { 
   println "now that 'independentTask' is done, I can continue to do complex things..." 
}

task independentTask << {
   // initialization stuff 
   println "doing a lot of initialization" 
}

task doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimselfPart1 << {
   println "doing really complex things"
}

task doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimselfPart2 << {
   println "doing other really complex things"
}

// we declare all tasks relationships separately
dependenTask.dependsOn doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimselfPart2
doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimselfPart2 dependsOn doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimselfPart1, jar
doComplexThingsThatTheUserShouldNeverDoHimselfPart1 dependsOn independentTask
```

Personally, I prefer the last one, the relationship block being more readable.